# めちゃくちゃ寒いもん : Because it is freezing, or because it would be freezing?

Tags: meaning

【たるひ】「窓も開けられなかったしね」

【瞠】「冬場に窓を開ける必要なんてないだろ」

【たるひ】「うん、その意見には諸手をあげて賛成ー。**めちゃくちゃ寒いもん**」

【三橋】「ふたりとも窓際の席だもんね、あそこ冷えるんだよねー」

In the conversation above I am unsure of what is meant by めちゃくちゃ寒いもん.
From what I can see, this could either be interpreted as :

1) If the windows were opened then it would be freezing

2) It is freezing, therefore the windows shouldn't be opened (because it would become even colder).

Whilst they both revolve around the idea of opening the window making things colder, they focus on different things.

Could someone clarify which of these (or any other) ways is the correct way of understanding this utterance in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the following context:

Taruhi: We couldn’t open the window.

Miharu: We don’t need to open the window. Do we?

Taruhi: Yes. I completely agree with your opinion. (Because) it’s terribly cold (outside).

Mihashi: Both of us are seated in the window-side. It’s so cold over there.

I take the part in question - めちゃくちゃ寒いもん for “(because) it’s terribly cold
outside, (and we’ll be frozen with flow-in of cold air, if we open window.”

“めちゃくちゃ寒いもん” apparently refers to the present status, and not the situation that can be supposed to happen after opening the window.

Comment: Could the third line be "Taruhi: Yes. I completely agree with your opinion. It (opening the window) would be silly because it’s terribly cold (outside)"?

Comment: "Taruhi: Yes." >>「We don't, do we?」に対して日本語で「はい / うん」は英語でNoです・・・

Comment: I think Yoichi Oishi is along the right lines, but I think it's because it is already cold inside during winter(based on 三橋 comment). Therefore there is no need to open the window to make it even colder.